Why do we stay at the rotating frame when considering an atom and field interaction in the Rabi problem
In the Atom-Field interaction chapter of the Steck Quantum Optics book, he considers a two level atom interacting with an elecromagnetic wave in the dipole approximation. This leads to a 2X2 Hamiltonian with time-dependent terms in the rotating wave approximation. The book uses a unitary transformation on the Hamiltonian to consider it in the rotating frame where the explicit time dependencies are hidden away and the differential equations become easier. He then derives time-evolved states and energies using this Hamiltonian.
What I do not understand is why he stays in the rotated frame at the end. Shouldn't he re-transform the states and the energies so that they are in the non rotating frame since this is where we do our measurements?

Is this calculation done with a classical EM field or a quantized one?

Yep, Classical!
